# Prevent commas in open text columns from messing up spark read csv

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delimiter

I have a directory of CSVs that has some text columns that DO NOT have quotes around them (I cannot control this as these are from an external source).  These open text columns have commas in them and as a result reading them is causing issues.  How do I properly escape them so Spark doesn't interpret them as new columns?

Sample code and Data:

```
file1 = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("quote", "'").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("file.csv")
```

Sample Data

[image]

The other relevant detail is I'm actually pulling these files using AWS Glue from an S3 bucket (recursively) so reading them as pandas dataframes and then transforming them into spark dataframes isn't an option.  The code above is on some local data I'm using for testing.

Expanded table:

| ID | Note | Sum | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello, there friend, what is going on. How are you?,,, | 123 | ACTIVE | 56 |
| 2 | yo, yo ,yo, what is up | 213 | INACTIVE | 5 |
| 3 | how are you, whats up, I'm fine. How are you,? | 2 | ACTIVE | 123 |

Comment: I am guessing you need to fix the file before you can read into dataframe, maybe with `sc.parallelize(csv lines).map(add quote somehow).toDF()`  What column do you have after Note?

Comment: @Emma several columns of varying data types

Comment: What is after the `Note`?  Could you include some sample rows in plain text in the question?

Comment: Do you actually have 56 on Status column and ACTIVE in Count column? Also how big is the csv?

Comment: @Emma So it's a directory of CSVs that I hope to be able to read recursively from S3.  Sorry that was a typo!

Comment: It's rather confusing what you have. Your "sample data" is an image file, your filename ends with "csv", and you say you have a dataframe. A dataframe is a object type, so that refers to data within a program, while a csv is really just a text string. Are you having trouble outputting the data? Or is the issue that while inputting data, commas are being incorrectly interpreted as delimitators? If the latter, how are the tables you show being created?

Comment: How well does your sample data represent the actual (each line is a number, then text, then a number, then "INACTIVE" or "ACTIVE", then a number, and the IDs are sequential)?

Comment: @Accumulation edited for clarity

Comment: @Accumulation, isn't super representative

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @blackbishop. There is no magic to read this type of data without any string manipulation. That's sort of why I asked what is after Note column. Only way to handle is to either change the delimiter or insert the double quotes to wrap the Note column.

@blackbishop shows how to change the delimiter.  This is the slightly different solution to insert the double quotes but other answer already mentioned the important things.

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file.csv")
header = rdd.first()
rows = (rdd.filter(lambda x: x != header)
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r'^(\d+,)(.*)(,\d+,(IN)?ACTIVE.*)', r'\1"\2"\3', x)))

df = spark.read.csv(rows).toDF('ID', 'Note', 'Sum', 'Status', 'Count')
```

If you have double quote in the Note column, I guess you need to escape the double quote (I haven't done that in the answer above).